# how to use useContext Hook for sharing States

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

i have a component `ListItem`

which contains a list element which state changes when clicked on

```
function ListItem(props) {
  const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false);

  console.log(isActive)
  return <li className={isActive ? 'selected': null}  onClick={(e)=> setActive(!isActive)}>{props.value}</li>;
}
```

Which is being used in the `ChooseElements` comp to create a list from an array

I want to retrieve the data from all list element which state is `true`

```
function ChooseElements() {
 
  const listItems = elementObjects.map((object) =>
  
    <ListItem key={object.id.toString()} value={object.Element} />
  );
  return (
    <div>   
    <ul>
      {listItems}
    </ul>

    <button onClick={listItems.forEach(element => { console.log(element)}) }>get Elements</button>
    {/*  with button click get all list items with specific class! */}
    </div>
 
  );
}
```

I have found the [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext) to share share conext value between components
but it looks like the the context is defined outside the components and then accecced by the components.
Can I implement my request with this hook?

Comment: You really don't need a context here, all you need is https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: `onClick={listItems.forEach(...) ` - this won't wait for the `onClick` event to execute the `forEach` method; it will be executed immediately. Change it to: `onClick={() => listItems.forEach(element => { console.log(element)}) `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments to solution here is to lift the state up into the parent component.
`ListItem` becomes a "dumb" component that only uses its props while the state is kept in `ChooseElements`:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const elementObjects = [
  { id: 1, Element: "element-1" },
  { id: 2, Element: "element-2" },
  { id: 3, Element: "element-3" },
  { id: 4, Element: "element-4" }
];

function ListItem({ isActive, toggleItem, value }) {
  return (
    <li className={isActive ? "selected" : null} onClick={toggleItem}>
      {value}
    </li>
  );
}

function ChooseElements() {
  const [activeItems, setActiveItems] = useState(new Set());

  const toggleItem = (id) => {
    const updatedItems = new Set(activeItems);
    if (updatedItems.has(id)) {
      updatedItems.delete(id);
    } else {
      updatedItems.add(id);
    }
    setActiveItems(updatedItems);
  };

  const listItems = elementObjects.map((object) => (
    <ListItem
      key={object.id.toString()}
      value={object.Element}
      isActive={activeItems.has(object.id)}
      toggleItem={() => toggleItem(object.id)}
    />
  ));

  return (
    <div>
      <ul>{listItems}</ul>

      <button
        onClick={() => {
          /*  with button click get all list items with specific class! */
          console.log(elementObjects.filter((o) => activeItems.has(o.id)));
        }}
      >
        get Elements
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ChooseElements />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit infallible-banzai-u1o7v]

Comment: can you explain this line `const updatedItems = new Set(activeItems); ` If I instead insert just a `new Set` the changes getting displayed after a second re render